# Hibernate session closed after time

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to test my application on a home webserver running ubuntu, but it has come to my attention that if i let a session open and then i come back some time later and try to login it throws this error:

```
Reason: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:
```

and if i try to login again it throws this error:

```
Reason: Could not roll back Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed
```

I don't have anything else to work with, because the logs are not working even tough they did on windows.

also im not totally sure that the reason for this is letting the session on, or is just for because of the long time of inactivity.
I know there's too little information to work with, but i hope someone can give some advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each when you request for any database operation you have to open the session and close the session after you complete

Comment: you cannot keep the session for a long time, it has to be closed to release the DB connection if that session is holding it.